# Waiting for async function in for loop

Tags: node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I need to wait for an async method (a call to my database) for every object in an array. Right now I have a for loop going through the array  calling the async method on each object. The async function is successful but I need to wait for every async call to finish before moving on. Doing some research I have found that Promises combined with await or other methods are the solution to my problem but I haven't been able to figure it out. Here is my code I have right now.

**Here is my class with the async function**

```
Vacation : class Vacation {
    constructor(id, destination, description, attendee_creator_id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.description = description;
        this.attendee_creator_id = attendee_creator_id;
        this.creator = undefined;
        this.votes = undefined;
    }
    find_creator(pool){
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var self = this;
            var query = "SELECT * FROM vacation_attendee WHERE id = " + self.attendee_creator_id;
            pool.query(query, function(error, result) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("Error in query for vacation creator " + error);
                    return reject(error);
                }
            var creator = new attendee.VacationAttendee(result.rows[0].full_name, result.rows[0].email, result.rows[0].password_hash);
            self.creator = creator;
            console.log("creator found ----> " + self.creator.full_name + "in " + self.destination);
            resolve(true);
        });
      })
    }
```

**here is how i'm calling the async function**

```
function get_all_vacations(callback) {
        var sql_vacations_query = "SELECT * FROM vacation";    
        pool.query(sql_vacations_query, function(error, vacations_query_result) {        
            if (error) {
                console.log("error in vacations query " + error);
                callback(error);
            }
            var all_complete = loop_through_vacations(vacations_query_result.rows, pool);
            callback(null, all_complete);
            });
    }


async function loop_through_vacations(vacations_incomplete, pool) {
    var all_vacations = [];
    for (var vacation_data of vacations_incomplete) {
        var vacation_at_index = new vac.Vacation(vacation_data.id, vacation_data.destination, vacation_data.description, vacation_data.attendee_creator_id);            
        vacation_at_index.find_creator(pool)
            .then(()=> {
                all_vacations.push(vacation_at_index);
            })
            .catch(error=> {
                console.log(error);
            });
        console.log("passed vacation " + vacation_at_index.destination);
    }
    return await Promise.all(all_vacations);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it in a wrong way, you don't wait anything in you `for-loop`.

`return await Promise.all(all_vacations);` does not work, because `all_vacations` is not a Promise array.

In your case, we have many way to do this, my way just is a example: Create a array to store all promises what have been created in your `for-loop`, then wait until the all promises finished by `Promise.all` syntax.

```
async function loop_through_vacations(vacations_incomplete, pool) {
  var all_vacations = [];
  var promises = []; // store all promise
  for (var vacation_data of vacations_incomplete) {
    var vacation_at_index = new vac.Vacation(vacation_data.id, vacation_data.destination, vacation_data.description, vacation_data.attendee_creator_id);
    promises.push( // push your promise to a store - promises
      vacation_at_index.find_creator(pool)
        .then(() => {
          all_vacations.push(vacation_at_index)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err); // Skip error???
        })
    );
  }
  await Promise.all(promises); // wait until all promises finished
  return all_vacations;
}
```

I don't know why you use `async/await` mix with `callback` style, I recommend `async/await` for any case:

Mix style:

```
function get_all_vacations(callback) {
  var sql_vacations_query = "SELECT * FROM vacation";
  pool.query(sql_vacations_query, async function(error, vacations_query_result) { // async
    if (error) {
      console.log("error in vacations query " + error);
      return callback(error); // return to break process
    }
    var all_complete = await loop_through_vacations(vacations_query_result.rows, pool); // await
    callback(null, all_complete);
  });
}
```

`async/await`:

```
async function get_all_vacations() {
  var sql_vacations_query = "SELECT * FROM vacation";
  var rows = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query(sql_vacations_query, function(error, vacations_query_result) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("error in vacations query " + error);
        return reject(error);
      }
      resolve(vacations_query_result.rows);
    });
  })
  var all_complete = await loop_through_vacations(rows, pool); // await
  return all_complete;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your input, I'm going to spend some time studying it to figure it out. I implemented your suggestions but now the code just hangs, I tried to do
var all_vacations = get_all_vacations(); 
console.log(all_vacations) // but I do not see anything in the console.

Comment: So your code was pushing the same vacation object, I modified and it is working now. But I just can't see why was it doing it. This is what I changed
 `vacation_at_index.find_creator(pool)
        .then((vacation) => {//i modified the Promise.resolve in my Vacation Class
          all_vacations.push(vacation)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err); // Skip error???
        })
    );`

Comment: Also, I'm very sorry about the formatting of my stuff, I'm sort of new to this lol.

Answer (score 0):

For me, you can try to reformat your SQL queries, the code will be cleaner and it will take less time to make a big query once than multiple queries.

If I understand joins in your database:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM vacation_attendee AS attendee 
INNER JOIN vacation ON vacation.attendee_creator_id = attendee.id
-- WHERECLAUSEYOUWANT
```

Then:

```
async function get_all_vacations(callback){
    const allComplete = await makeThatBigQuery(); // + treat data as you want
    callback(null, allComplete);
}
```

In your definition of get_all_vacations you don't wait all_complete, so the callback is called before all_complete is ready

Comment: FrV, thank you for your suggestion but I need help with waiting for all the async calls  in the for loop to finish.

Comment: Just update the answer, if realy want to continue with the way you took, you have to return the prosime.all without await, in get_all_vacations -> var all_complete = await loop_through_vacations(vacations_query_result.rows, pool);

Answer (score 0):

This is how the await/promises part of the code should look like:

```
function get_all_vacations(callback) {
    var sql_vacations_query = "SELECT * FROM vacation";    
    pool.query(sql_vacations_query, async function(error, vacations_query_result) {        
        if (error) {
            console.log("error in vacations query " + error);
            callback(error);
        }
        var all_complete = await loop_through_vacations(vacations_query_result.rows, pool);
        callback(null, all_complete);
    });
}


async function loop_through_vacations(vacations_incomplete, pool) {
    const promises = [];
    for (var vacation_data of vacations_incomplete) {
        var vacation_at_index = new vac.Vacation(vacation_data.id, vacation_data.destination, vacation_data.description, vacation_data.attendee_creator_id);            
        promises.push(vacation_at_index.find_creator(pool));
    }
    return await Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Ideally you should be removing all the callbacks(not sure if asyn/await is supported for pool.query methods) and change the whole code to async/await style. Also you should be resolving the promise from 'find_creator' with `resolve(creator)`, so that the value is obtained when the promise is resolved.